# Difference in rendering firefox images

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a tab pane that is basically a line of 6 images, all floated.  They are all red and the bottom border is set to `4px white` by default.  When a tab is selected, the 4px border turns `red`.  Unfortunately in firefox though, there is a space between the content and the border.  Right now it's a button with an image inside of it.  The 1px margin between the buttons is intentional and working as expected.

The margin/padding/image-border/etc are all zero, according to the development pane, but there is still a 1px white line between the content and border ?????

You can view the webpage here:

www.bookyoursite.com/more/1

The following is the buttons with their images within:

```
 <div id="buttonContainer">
        <button id="button1" class="buttons" onclick="hideAllBut('tab',1)"><img src="/images/buttons/sites.png" /></button>
        <button id="button2" class="buttons" onclick="hideAllBut('tab',2)"><img src="/images/buttons/rates.png" /></button>
        <button id="button3" class="buttons" onclick="hideAllBut('tab',3)"><img src="/images/buttons/recreation.png" /></button>
        <button id="button4" class="buttons" onclick="hideAllBut('tab',4)"><img src="/images/buttons/facilities.png" /></button>
        <button id="button5" class="buttons" onclick="hideAllBut('tab',5)"><img src="/images/buttons/ratings.png" /></button>
        <button id="button6" class="buttons" onclick="hideAllBut('tab',6)"><img src="/images/buttons/nearby.png" /></button>
 </div>
```

CSS assosiated with the above:

```
   #buttonContainer {
      font-size:0;
      text-align:center;
      border-image-width:0;
   }
   .buttons{
      font-size:inherit;
      position:relative;
      padding:0;
      border:none;
      background-color:transparent;
      width:90px;
      margin-right:1px;
      border-bottom:4px solid white;

      border-image-width:inherit;
   }
   .buttons img {
      padding:0;
      border-image-width:inherit;
   }
```

For completeness I'll include the onclick code ... but this is probably not useful:

```
function hideAllBut(name,n){ //hides all other items with name, and then displays the selected tab's pane
   for (i = 1;i <= 1000; i ++){
      p = document.getElementById(name + i);
      if (p == null)break;
      p.style.display="none";
      document.getElementById("button" + i).style.borderBottom="4px solid white"
   }
   document.getElementById(name + n).style.display="block";
   document.getElementById("button" + n).style.borderBottom="4px solid red"
}
```

In Chrome and IE, the tabs render as desired

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the images to `display: block`